# Stochastic matrix and its commutant

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

This is an interview question that I saw online.

> $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix. Each element of $A$ is independently sampled from a normal distribution $N(0,1)$. $B$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix that satisfies $AB=BA$. What is the dimension of the space of $B$?

---

I guess my biggest confusion is whether the answer depends on what $A$ really is. For example, there is a chance that $A$ is a matrix of zeros or the identity, in which case $B$ can be any $n$ by $n$ matrix, so that the dimension of the space of $B$ that commutes with $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. However, if $A$ is generic, then it seems to me that the only way $B$ can commute with $A$ is when $B$ is a multiple of the identity or when $B$ is a multiple of $A$, spanning a dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: In an interview one can always ask back what was meant exactly and typically interview questions should not be that sophisticated to trigger a research project. It is totally correct -as you say- that the only matrices that commute with arbitrary $A$ are multiples of the identity.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the space under consideration is the space of matrices $B$ satisfying $AB = BA$ for all matrices $A$ (or perhaps "with probability 1") or whether the space of matrices $B$ satisfying $AB = BA$ for a *particular* matrix $A$, which would make the dimension of the space a random variable whose distribution is the subject of the question.